# C++ with Extern "C" causing Duplicate Symbols Error

Tags: c++, extern, include-guards

I am trying to use a extern "C" function inside my header file for a c++ class.

When I compile I keep getting the error

```
duplicate symbol _currentInstance in:
main.o
GLHandler.o
```

I thought I had the right guards but can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the header file.

```
#ifndef GLHANDLER_H
#define GLHANDLER_H

#include "LoadedObject.h"


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
void displayCallback();
}
#endif



class GLHandler {

private:
    LoadedObject *object;

public:
    GLHandler(LoadedObject *);
    void initializeVBO(LoadedObject *);
    void renderObject(struct model *);
    void displayFunction(void);
    model *createModel(void);
    void setupDisplayCallback();


};

GLHandler *currentInstance;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#endif

#endif
```

EDIT: Quickly pointed out by David, the extern GLHandler *currentInstance fixed the error.

Comment: Maybe that should be `extern GLHandler *currentInstance;`?

Comment: You're certainly implementing this function both in main.c and GLHandler.c. Or you're putting it into a header file and not inlining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with the `extern "C"` declaration - you're defining a global variable in the header, so it gets defined in each compilation unit:

```
GLHandler *currentInstance;
```

In the header, you should instead use:

```
extern GLHandler *currentInstance;
```

then in *exactly one* .cpp file have:

```
GLHandler *currentInstance;
```

As a side note, as it stands right now, the header is valid only for C++, since it has a class definition.  The `#ifdef __cplusplus` directives are pointless clutter (though harmless).